# Unable to open SSH tunnel to EMR's master node

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-emr, apache-zeppelin

Am trying to access Zepplein on EMR, I have followed the instructions as specified on the aws site.

When I try to open SSH tunnel using my laptop

`ssh -i pemfile.pem -ND 8157 hadoop@192.2.2.12`

I get error as

```
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 3: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
channel 2: open failed: connect failed: Connection refused
```

I could establish tunnel using my old laptop with same .pem file and access zeppelin. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: have you set the security group of emr? maybe you need additional security group.

Comment: Before trying to tunnel, can you establish a normal SSH connection to the node? When it fails, does it return the error message immediately, or does it take some time before failing? Are you using the public IP address of the master node? What is the configuration of the security group on the master node?

Comment: @John, I am able to make normal SSH connection to the node from the laptop on which am getting the error! I am using public IP address of the node. Configuration on security group has inbound rule which allows all connection from my vpn on port 22

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than using `-D` (which uses the SOCKS protocol), try using `-L`.

For example:

```
ssh -i key.pem -L 8890:localhost:8890 hadoop@MASTER-PUBLIC-IP
```

This will forward port 8890 on your local computer to the master node, which will send it to `localhost:8890`.

Then, connect to Zeppelin in your local web browser with:

```
http://localhost:8890
```

Comment: I was struggling for hours, this helped Thanks John